# Browser Promise.all is not working in ios 7.1.2

Tags: ios, cordova, pouchdb

I am storing my server data inside the pouch db in an iterative process by using browser supported promise `Promise.all()`. Which working well in `ios 9.2` and `android` but its having problems in `ios 7.1.2`. Any other way is there to make work in `ios 7.1.2` with the same piece of code. Can anyone help me (:.

Comment: promises aren't supported on iOS 7 http://caniuse.com/#search=promise

Comment: Any alternative solution is there to make it work in iOS 7.

Comment: search for promises polyfills, I don't know any, sorry